# Firebase + Angular app is losing session upon refreshing twice

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

Here I have an application made with Firebase and Angular.
After signing in, I lose my token upon refreshing twice.
I've already set the session persistence with:

```
await firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
```

First, I've tried to put it in the `AuthenticationService`'s constructor.
so It didn't work.

Second, I've tried to put it in the main app component to make sure it always runs.
also didn't work.

Third, I've tried to put before every sign-in call.
didn't work either.

Do someone know what am I missing?

Comment: Got the same issue. Have you been able to solve this?